# Rails - when a row returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, null

I'm getting this error when loading my view that has a Model User that has no records in it.  I simply want it to return "Unassigned" in the view if there is no record. Otherwise, display the first and last name of the User. Displaying User first and last name works as expected when a record exists.

I've messed around with many different combinations of this and can't see to get it to work.

Error:

```
undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass
```

In **tickets.index.html.erb**:

```
<% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
  <%= ticket.user.full_name %>
<% end %>
```

In **ticket.rb** Model

```
def full_name
  if full_name.blank?
    full_name = "Unassigned"
  else
    ticket.user.first_name + ' ' + ticket.user.last_name    
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `ticket.user` that might be nil, so you can't call anything on it. You have the right idea in making a method on your Ticket model to isolate this, but it's calling itself which will get an infinite loop, and also you're still calling the method on your user and not your ticket. Try this:

In your view:

```
<% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
  <%= ticket.full_name %>
<% end %>
```

In your ticket model:

```
def full_name
  if user.nil?
    return "Unassigned"
  else
    return user.full_name
  end
end
```

And in your user model:

```
def full_name
  return "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

I made the user model have its own method for this so it's further isolated (following OO practices).